# How to display user information?

Tags: 8, theming, users

I copied the user twig file into my theme.

How to display the information of the following user:

> - Account updated on: ???
> - Account status: ???
> - Roles: ???
> - Member since: ???
> - Last connection on: ???

I tried `{{ user.role }}` and `{{ content.role }}` to display the role, but it does not work.

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to present all user data.
 *
 * This template is used when viewing a registered user's page,
 * e.g., example.com/user/123. 123 being the user's ID.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - content: A list of content items. Use 'content' to print all content, or
 *   print a subset such as 'content.field_example'. Fields attached to a user
 *   such as 'user_picture' are available as 'content.user_picture'.
 * - attributes: HTML attributes for the container element.
 * - user: A Drupal User entity.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_user()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
<article{{ attributes.addClass('user--full') }}>

  <div class="bs-region-header row">

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 bs-left">
      Compte mise à jour le : ???
      Compte : ???
      Rôles : ???
      Membre depuis : ???
      Dernière connexion le : ???
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 bs-right">
      {{ drupal_view('utilisateur_offre', 'block_1') }}
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 bs-region-footer">
    {{ drupal_view('utilisateur_offre_detail', 'block_1') }}
  </div>

</article>
```

Comment: We don’t need a new question for each couple of variables you need to render in the same template. If you don’t know how to identify what variables are available, please research _that_ and ask a detailed question if you fail to come up with an answer. Your question should include details of the research, and examples of the code you’ve tried, so answers don’t cover ground that you’ve already identified as irrelevant. Many thanks

Comment: To add to what @Clive said, you should make clear what you don't understand in the task you are trying to achieve. The comment you copied together the template file says `user` is available in the template. Did you try using it? What exactly don't you understand, considering that in the other question you shown code using `{{ user.label }}`?

Comment: And like the other question... most of this is solved / easily solved in Views.

Comment: @Kevin There is no way without sight? Why not directly in twig? Regarding status (online, absent or busy) the only way is to use EVA. I think twig could do that.

Comment: Because for the amount of logic you’ll have to write in preprocess or twig to get what you want can be done in 5 seconds with Views and embedabble as a block into twig or other means of code based embedding.

Comment: @drup8 If I might say, your approach here isn't the best. You're looking at the finish line but not putting the training in to be able to actually run the race effectively. Ask yourself: _what's the smallest amount of information I need to progress to the next little bit?_. If I was in your position the answer might be _I need to identify what properties this `user` object has_. That leads to a google search of "drupal debug twig variables", which after a bit of reading leaves you able to view those properties. And then repeat...

Comment: ...If at any stage you can't find an answer yourself, you have all the ingredients to ask a good question here: a focused problem, which you've tried to find a solution for, plenty of context to provide because you have a bigger end-goal than the more narrowly-scoped question, probably some relevant code attempts for even more context, allowing people to either tell you straight away that you're heading in the wrong direction, or tell you that you've picked the right approach but haven't quite implemented it correctly, and so on.